# How can PC's be bottlenecked by GPUs if they have gotten so much faster than CPUs over the last 5 years?

Tags: cpu, gpu, gaming, benchmarking

I am thinking of upgrading my gaming PC. Currently, my specs are:

- **CPU**: Intel Core i5-4690K,
- **GPU**: Nvidia GeForce GTX 970

According to [this](https://pc-builds.com/calculator/Core_i5-4690K/GeForce_GTX_970/0AQ0LElu/8/100), I am currently slightly bottlenecked by my CPU. I am considering following the [PCMR builds](https://pcmasterrace.org/builds) and getting the high refresh rate ultra build. This would mean upgrading my specs to:

- **CPU**: Intel Core i5-10400
- **GPU**: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070

I am confused because according to [this](https://pc-builds.com/calculator/Core_i5-10400/GeForce_RTX_2070/0Yh12xlu/16/100), I will be slightly bottlenecked by the GPU. According to [this](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-970-vs-Nvidia-RTX-2070S-Super/2577vs4048), the GPU speed should increase by 133% and according to [this](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i5-4690K-vs-Intel-Core-i5-10400/2432vs4073), the CPU speed should increase by 13%.

I will only be upgrading the speed of the CPU by 13% and the speed of the GPU by 133% yet this causes the GPU to bottleneck the system? Surely with such a large relative boost to the GPU speed, the CPU should bottleneck the system?

Comment: Do you understand you will have to change your motherboard

Comment: Yes. I am trying to understand why a 13% increase in CPU speed seems to help with gaming more than a 133% increase in GPU speed. Why do I not need to increase both speeds equally?

Comment: I would argue there is more than a 13% performance difference between a processor released 5 years ago.  GPU difference is significant between a 970 and a 2070 but I am not sure I agree it’s 133%.  Those numbers are not considering the real performance gains.

Comment: Where do the numbers come from? I was assuming a 10% increase in GPU speed means a 10% increase in FPS (assuming no bottleneck from other components e.g. CPU).

Comment: Just a note about those online tools you are looking for: They are not for the benefit of the consumer if they place ads against the data. The reality is doing math against competing specs seems logical… But many times the math doesn’t factor in real work usage and interactions. The whole purpose of sites like that is to drive traffic and get you thinking about buying PC parts. And once you are thinking like that, you might click on a targeted ad designed just for your impulse purchase weaknesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @theJack answer - but would like to expand on it and re-emphasise the relative importance of CPU and GPU is very load-type specific.   A system which will be doing a lot of compiling of source code to program code will  hardly benefit much from a GPU, while a game will benefit much more from a GPU then a CPU.

Your CPU comparison is also flawed. A better starting point for the comparison between your CPU's is https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-i5-4690K-vs-Intel-i5-10400/2284vs3737
. While you will get about an 18% performance increase per core, the i5-10400 blows the i5-4690k out the water on a wholistic comparison where more then a single core is used - it will perform up to 2.5 times as fast - and if you are using it for gaming the 2.5 times performance increase is likely to be close to the mark as games typically will take advantage of multiple threads and multiple CPUs.

Your "Bottleneck Calculator" link is of little real-world value - it even says " Please do not use this calculator primary as decision maker than as helping tool to understand performance correlations between different components.".  My takeaway from that link is that the i5 CPU and RTX2040 GPU are well paired.  **In gaming applications the GPU is much more important then the CPU** - because it is designed to handle the very specific workloads games require.

Comment: According to https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare/GeForce-GTX-970-vs-GeForce-RTX-2070/2954vs4001 your new GPU should be a little under twice as fast as the old one for "3d" content - the 133% is about right for 2d content.  Most of the games that will want a good GPU are 3d though.

Answer (score 2):

The system could still be bottlenecked by the GPU if the load uses the GPU more than the CPU.  What causes the bottleneck in the system depends on the use case.  Games tend to be more GPU bound than CPU bound, i. e. it is easier to satisfy the CPU requirements than the GPU requirements, because of the way games run.

You can think about it by considering two simplified scenarios:  Consider a terminal text editor.  It runs by reading user input, modifying some memory, and displaying the output.  Most of its work is done by the CPU, and almost none of it is done by the GPU because of its simple interface.  So, the system will be CPU bound as most of the work is done by the CPU, and even massive increases in GPU performance will lead to negligible performance increases.  Now consider a rendering engine.  It runs by loading a scene into the graphics memory, then using the GPU to render it.  So, the system will be GPU bound because it mostly uses the GPU, and increasing the CPU performance will have little impact on the overall performance.

Games function more like the latter, as the hardest work is rendering the output.  They don't usually max out the CPU, but they will often max out the GPU if you let them.